# Image of real and imaginary axis under $f(z)= \frac {2z-1} {2-z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to find the image of real and imaginary axis under $f(z)= \frac {2z-1} {2-z}$, I have proved that it maps unit disk and upper half to itself.In some book it is written that only looking at the image of $0$ and $\infty$ we can tell what is the image of real and imaginary axis, I know Möbius transformation maps lines and circles to lines or circles. Please help me

Answer (score 3):

Linear fractional transformations, i.e. mappings of the form $\displaystyle z\mapsto\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$, map circles in $\mathbb C$ to circles, provided one construes straight lines as circles of infinite radius.

This mapping takes $0$, $1$, and $-1$ to real numbers; therefore it takes $\mathbb R\cup\{\infty\}$ to itself.  It takes $0$, $i$, and $-i$ to $-1/2$, $-(4/5)+(3/5)i$ and $-(4/5)-(3/5)i$ respectively.  Therfore it takes the imaginary axis to the circle that passes through those three points.  It takes $\infty$ to $-2$, which is also on that circle.  The diameter is $3/2$.  Draw the picture and you'll see the center at $-5/4$ and the Pythagorean theorem will confirm that the distance from there to either of $-(4/5)\pm(3/5)i$ is $3/4$.

Comment: can we find the center without drawing it?

Comment: @Mathematician : Yes.  The fact that the coefficients are real means there's symmetry about the real axis.  So look at where $0$ is mapped to ($-1/2$) and where $\infty$ is mapped to ($-2$), and notice that both are real, and the center is half-way between those points.

Comment: The answer is well explained ,but can you please tell how $3/2$  is radius?

Comment: @TheStudent : I said the _diameter_, not the radius, is $3/2.$ Just use the Pythagorean theorem to find the distance from any of the three points I said are on the circle to the one that I said was the center. If I didn't know where the center is, I would find the midpoint between $-1/2$ and $(-4+3i)/5$ and note that the slope of the line through those two points is $-2,$ and so I would consider the line through that midpoint whose slope is $+1/2.$ That line's $x$-intercept is at $-5/4,$ so that's the center.